# Python runs more then it should for recursion

Tags: python, recursion, functional-programming

i am trying to write some recursion in the python. I want to calculate A+b-A*B and keep calculating it through all the elements in the list. The code runs more than I expect. I think the two 0.5+add() print come from the 0.4+add() case because it has two add([0.5, 0.2]) in the expression. Please correct me if i am wrong. But the base case print confuessed me the most. I don't understand why it has 4. It would be great if someone can explain what are these 4 base come from and the execution order.

This is my first question here. Thanks!

Code:

```
lst= [0.4,0.5,0.2]

def add(l):
    if len(l) == 1:
        print('base call:', l[0])
        return l[0]
    else:
        print('{zero}+add({one})-{zero}*add({one})'.format(zero=l[0], one=l[1:]))
        return l[0]+add(l[1:])-l[0]*add(l[1:])

print('result of add: ', add(lst))
```

Shell:

```
0.4+add([0.5, 0.2])-0.4*add([0.5, 0.2])
0.5+add([0.2])-0.5*add([0.2])
base call: 0.2
base call: 0.2
0.5+add([0.2])-0.5*add([0.2])
base call: 0.2
base call: 0.2
result of add:  0.76
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function is doubly recursive: each invocation makes two more calls.  When you first call `add`, you give it the list of all three elements.  This makes two calls, each one using `[0.5, 0.2]`, as you've properly traced.

Now, *each* of those calls makes two more calls, using `[0.2]` as the list `l`.  That's a total of *four* calls at this level, with a list of length 1.  Each of those four calls is a base case; each one produces one of your "base case" prints.

This is easier to see if you indent your `print` statements according to the recursion level.  Then, the output looks like this:

```
0.4+add([0.5, 0.2])-0.4*add([0.5, 0.2])
  0.5+add([0.2])-0.5*add([0.2])
    base call: 0.2
    base call: 0.2
  0.5+add([0.2])-0.5*add([0.2])
    base call: 0.2
    base call: 0.2
result of add:  0.76
```

Does that clear up the confusion?

Comment: Yes,  I understand it now. It comes from the add([0.2]) and there are 4 of them. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Excellent!  Remember to select a "best answer", so that Stack Overflow can properly archive the question.